# What's this little white circle on my Mac's screen?

Tags: macos, applications

Can anyone help me identify this little circle on the screen of my Mac?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different :) Try quitting apps one by one in the Menu bar status area. See if quitting any one of them does away with the circle and you're able to catch the culprit!

Comment: Maybe it's a portal to another dimension?

Comment: Boot into a safe mode (hold Shift while booting).  Does it go away?

Comment: Have you tried changing to a different desktop pic? Something similar happened to me, turns out the picture got modified somehow.

Comment: Thank you all for your help. @NimeshNeema Yes, it was MacID that was the culprit!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to catch the culprit is to quit running apps (both in Dock and Menu bar) one by one until the circle goes away.

As identified by OP by following the above mentioned approach, the circle is created by an app called [MacID](https://macid.co) which along with along with it's companion iOS app [Unlox](https://unlox.it) lets one unlock their Mac using their iOS device.